# online music on XBMC

Tags: kodi, script

Is there a functional script for XBMC (on a raspi, obviously) that allows to listen to online music coming from grooveshark , spotify or whatever... needed NO premium or anyhow or pay-for-it account ??

I can hear infinite music from my PC for free at grooveshark so .. why not from the Pi ?

Comment: it's definitely possible. but you need to add some details and what you tried in your question. how do you want to choose which title or url should be played by the pi? you could create a .m3u playlist and have it playing by xbmc at start with a autoexec.py in your userdata folder..

Comment: @Gotschi : have you ever used grooveshark? or spotify? Any of those, or a simiar one that I dont know, will work. I just want to be able to search and play. If you have ever used one of those you know what I mean, if you haven't I recommend you to try grooveshark :)

Comment: i certainly know them, but i still use youtube ;) just put raspbian on it, load chrome and off you go to grooveshark, wheres the problem?